# How does will() actually test anything?

Tags: 8, testing

I'm beginning to learn about writing tests for Drupal 8 via PHPUnit and am unclear on how the `will()` method actually serves to test anything.

Given this code (derived from examples and tutorials on the Internet):

```
$this->myClass = $this
  ->getMockBuilder(MyClass::class)
  ->getMock();

$this->myClass
  ->expects($this->any())
  ->method('getTestValue')
  ->will($this->returnValue('abc'));

$this->assertEquals('abc', $this->myClass->getTestValue());
```

If I'm just telling it to return value 'abc' and then, unsurprisingly, I get the same value back, then what am I testing? As far as I can tell, the `getTestValue` method of MyClass doesn't even get called. I verified this by coding `MyClass->getTestValue` to return a test-breaking value (i.e. 'def'), but it still passes.

How does this test the `MyClass` class?

Admittedly, I also don't understand the usage of `expects()` and `method()`, but these seem ancillary to the actual question. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I’m not a testing expert, but you’d mock any dependencies MyClass depends on, so you can focus on testing the methods of MyClass. The code above as you stated, is useless as a test. If MyClass has no external dependencies, you may not need to mock anything. It really all depends on what you want to test, which is not so well articulated in how you get there as everyone has very different opinions on the matter.

Comment: Thank you! The part where you stated "If MyClass has no external dependencies, you may not need to mock anything" made it click for me. Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: All I can recommend is checking the tests in core for some examples for your use case. Also, share them back as examples. IMO definitely a knowledge gap needed in the community.

Comment: This is a plain PHP question, as the methods listed in the questions use PHPUNIT.